# Catching OutOfMemory Exceptions from HttpClient.GetAsync()

Tags: c#, asynchronous, exception, out-of-memory

I am performing a fairly simple HttpClient.GetAsync() call, and if the target of my call exists (it is a Web Service running on my local PC) then I get back data correctly and everything works as advertised. However, if the target of my call does NOT exist, I will occasionally get an OutOfMemory exception thrown. I cannot actually seem to catch this exception, however. Here's how I'm making the call:

NOTE: `proxy` is just a private `HttpClient` member of my class that's already been initialized/created.

```
public static T get(string methodNameParam)
{
   T returnValue = default(T);
   try 
   {
      string getString = $"remoteAPI/get/{methodNameParam}";
      HttpResponseMessage response = proxy.GetAsync(getString).Result;
      if(response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
      {
         String jsonString = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
         returnValue = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(jsonString);
      }
   }
   catch (Exception ex)
   {
      // log exception thrown, allow upper functions to manage it.
      logger.LogError($"Error Get {methodNameParam} ", ex);
      throw;
   }
   return returnValue;
}
```

The OutOfMemory exception is never caught, I assume because it's being thrown within the context of the Async call? How can I catch this exception, if only to log that it happened (currently my application crashes and burns).

---

EDIT: I updated the function based on Selvin's feedback, and it now looks like:

```
private static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> _get(string getString)
{
   HttpResponseMessage response = default(HttpResponseMessage);

   try
   {
      response = await proxy.GetAsync(getString);
   }
   catch (Exception ex)
   {
      logger.LogError($"Error (_get) - Caught Exception! ", ex);
   }

   return response;
}

public static T get(string methodNameParam)
{
   T returnValue = default(T);
   try 
   {
      string getString = $"remoteAPI/get/{methodNameParam}";
      HttpResponseMessage response = _get(getString).Result;
      if(response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
      {
         String jsonString = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
         returnValue = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(jsonString);
      }
   }
   catch (Exception ex)
   {
      // log exception thrown, allow upper functions to manage it.
      logger.LogError($"Error Get {methodNameParam} ", ex);
      throw;
   }
   return returnValue;
}
```

However, the VS19 debugger still catches the unhandled Out of Memory exception in the synchronous `get()` call at the call to `_get()` as soon as the `.GetAsync()` function is called.

Comment: `.Result` is bad m'kay? ... proper way is to await Task results, so change `static T get` to `static async Task<T> get` and use `jsonString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync()` (same story with `GetAsync`)

Comment: "*if the target of my call does NOT exist, I will occasionally get an OutOfMemory exception thrown*" I think this assumption is wrong. "*I cannot actually seem to catch this exception*" i also think this assumption is wrong, its likely being caught however the logging is not working and just rethrowing. And lastly as been stated, never call a blocking method on an async call. Just await the task.

Comment: @Selvin, I took your suggestion and wrapped the call in an async function - meaning I broke the call to ```.GetAsync()``` out and put it into a new async function that doesn't rely on using ```.Result``` and calls ```await``` on ```.GetAsync()```. Same behavior occurs - as soon as ```.GetAsync()``` is called, the synchronous top-level function breaks on the Out Of Memory exception at the wrapped async call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An `OutOfMemoryException` is an asynchronous exception -- you cannot guarantee that it will happen on a given thread.  And even if you catch it, your process might be in an inconsistent state, so you are probably better off allowing it to crash than protracting its almost-certain death.

Your best strategy might be to handle `AppDomain.UnhandledException` instead for logging purposes.  See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.appdomain.unhandledexception?view=net-5.0